# We offer our best wishes of success as you pursue your educational goals

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

> We greatly appreciate your interest in Harvard, and **we offer our best wishes of success as you pursue your educational goals**.

---

Does the bold part mean "*while you pursue your educational goals, we offer our best wishes of success*"?

Comment: It means "sorry you didn't get into Harvard"...

Comment: The clause _as you pursue your educational goals_ could be attached to the noun phrase _success_, or to the whole predicate _we offer our best wishes of success_. I doubt if anybody - including the writer - could tell which of these was intended.

Comment: @ColinFine I'm not sure if you are saying that the clause "*as you pursue your educational goals*" could be attached to "*our best wishes of success*" or just "*success*".

Comment: @Aaaaaaassssss: that's a third option I hadn't considered.

Comment: @ColinFine About the "the noun phrase success" in one of your replies, I wonder if success is a noun phrase. I think that it is a noun, not a noun phrase. What do you think about that?

Comment: _Success_ is a noun. It is also a noun phrase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is evidently the closing from a rejection letter.

The recipient has been rejected from Harvard, and so as they receive the letter they must change their plans and change their goals.  At the time that they being their new plans Harvard are sending "best wishes" (but nothing else)

It is quite common in a letter of goodbye to say "Best wishes as you go to do your new thing". A rejection letter is a way of saying "goodbye". And this phrasing makes it subtly clear that there is no possibility of the rejection being reconsidered or appealed.  It implies "your educational goals no longer include Harvard".